# How to structure data in Firebase created by one user but accessible to users in a group?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

So, let's say I have data like this:

```
{ 
  "events" : { 
   "s0d980983s" : 
    { creator: "bob@bob.com",
      text: "Bob says 'My name is Robert'" },
   "kjl34jl234j" : 
    { creator: "fred@fred.com",
      text: "Fred says 'My name is Fredrick'" }
  }
  "users" : { 
   "bob@bob.com" : { "paid": true },
   "fred@fred.com" : { "paid": false }
  }
}
```

I'm assuming this is the correct way to structure the data. When the data is created, I use the `push()` method to create a new key for the data, and then store the creator of the data inside it.

I'd like to make it so that:

- I can allow anyone from a group of users to access certain data (and disallow others obviously).
- The query is "optimized," meaning if I have thousands of records I am not iterating over all the data.

More concretely, for example, I want `lizzie@lizzie.com` to be able to see the `s0d980983s`.

I'm confused how to structure the data, and what my Firebase rules should look like.

Would it be something like this?

```
{ "events" : { 
  "s0d980983s" : 
    { creator: "bob@bob.com",
      viewers: { "bob@bob.com": true,
                 "lizzie@lizzie.com" : true },
      text: "Bob says 'My name is Robert'" },
 ...
}
```

I don't understand how I can search for events that are viewable by a group of users. I don't believe Firebase supports some kind of wildcard that would make this code work, right?

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref( "events/*/viewers/lizzie@lizzie.com" ).on(...);
```

Do I also want to reference the events inside my users table? I'm not sure I understand how to flatten data (denormalize it) and keep references in both places to support a query like this. Should I expect to make multiple queries where I first retrieve a list of events stored in a user object and then retrieve them one by one using their key? But, how do I put that logic into my firebase rules?

Comment: You can use wildcard locations when writing your security rules. This video might be helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUBnlbjZFAI

Answer (score 0):

```
{ "events" : { 
      "s0d980983s" : 
      { creator: "bob@bob.com",
        viewers: { "[insert bobs id]": true,
                    "[insert liz id]" : true 
                 },
      text: "Bob says 'My name is Robert'" },
      ...
}
```

Based on the above structure as you suggested, and if you are using firebase authentication to authenticate your user, you can add another 'read' or 'write' rule for checking whether that user is in the list of your 'viewers'. something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth != null && 
          root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('viewers').child(auth.uid).val() == 
          true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should help. [setting firebase security rules at a location/node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/)